# Transluent StatusBar remains its half-transparent shadow on Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-statusbar

Hey guys I have application where I use only one Activity. On that I have to manage between Transluent and non-Transluent statubar. I have issue that statusbar shadows remains its shadow on Navigation Drawer and I don't know why.

[image]

Initial state of the app is Transluent, due to used styles. So on the splash screen background is drawn below statusbar.

***style-23v***

```
<style name="MyBaseTheme.TransparentStatusBar">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
```

When user log in, I remove that transluent flags and I show Toolbar

***MainAcitvity.java***

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

***MyUtilities.java***

```
public void toggleTransluentStatusBar(boolean showTransluentBar){
    Window window = Manager.getActivity().getWindow();
    if(showTransluentBar){
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }else {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getStatusBarColor());
    }
}
```

doing this causes that content is fitting to the space left by status bar

Answer (score 1):

Add `app:insetForeground="@null"` to your `NavigationView`.